# Most efficient way to get all child records for a specific record

Tags: soql, dynamic-soql, sosl, describesobject

I have an account record that I want to get every single possible child record - ideally as a list of IDs.

Currently I am doing the following:

```
for(Opportunity opp : [SELECT ID From Opportunity WHERE AccountId =: accountId])
{
        idList.add(opp.Id);
}
// same for case
// same for customobject1 
// etc...
```

Is there a way I can do this efficiently and easily?

I had an idea to do something like:

```
Schema.DescribeSObjectResult R = Account.SObjectType.getDescribe();
// for each child object
// get parent relationship to account name
// build dynamic query
// database.execute('superlongquery');
// build list of ID from above query
```

Is this the best approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `DescribeSObjectResult` which will give you all the `ChildRelationships`, then loop through the `ChildRelationships` and build a dynamic query and collect all the `Ids` in a common `List` or `Set`.

```
Id accountId ='';//your accountid
Set<Id> idList = new Set<Id>();
DescribeSObjectResult describeResult = Account.SObjectType.getDescribe();
for (ChildRelationship childRelation : describeResult.getChildRelationships()) {
    if(childRelation.getChildSObject().getDescribe().isQueryable()){
        SObject[] sobjectRecords = Database.query('select Id from ' + childRelation.getChildSObject() + ' where ' + childRelation.getField() + ' = :accountId');
        for (SObject sobj : sobjectRecords) {
            idList.add(Id(sobj.get('Id')));
        }
    }
}
```

You can get further information on ChildRelationship on [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Schema_ChildRelationship.htm) link.

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what I needed. I had to add a check inside the loop to ensure the child object was queryable but it works perfectly.

`if(childRelation.getChildSObject().getDescribe().isQueryable())`

Comment: That's great !! Updated the answer with queryable check